# Primes of the form $(2m+1)^2-2^{2s+1}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

The question is the following :

- *Question:*

Does there exist infinitely many primes of the form $(2m+1)^2-2^{2s+1}$ with $m,s\geq 1$ ?

- *Why this could be true:*

Bunyakowsky conjecture would imply that the answer is *yes* for any given $s$.

[ Indeed, the polynomial $4X^2+4X-2^{2s+1}+1$ is irreducible ($\Delta = 2^{2s+5}$), and no integer $d\geq 1$ can divide all values $P(n)$ (since $P(0)$ is odd and $P(1)-P(0)=8$) ]

Unfortunately, as the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) indicates, Bunyakowsky conjecture is not known to hold for a single polynomial of degree $\geq 2$.

My hope is that allowing $s$ to assume infinitely many values can help ...

- *Why this could be hard:*

As was pointed out by Mike Benett in [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/219414/does-the-equation-24122s1-m2-have-a-solution), the density of primes of this form among primes that are congruent to $1$ mod $8$ is asymptotically $0$. (As an example, there are $20453$ primes $p<2^{20}$ that are congruent to $1$ mod. $8$, and only $1334$ among them that have the required form, so that the density up to that bound is only $0.065$).

Comment: The conjecture that there are infinitely many primes of form $(2m)^2+1$ is still open (and was listed as one of [Landau's four problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_problems) more than 100 years ago), so maybe this is another indication your question could be hard?

Comment: Do you also count *negative* prime values of your expression $(2m+1)^2 - 2^{2s+1}$?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen : Right ... as far as I know, Euler had already asked this very question.

Comment: @StefanKohl : definitely not ! The point is that these primes furnish interesting *real* quadratic extensions.

Comment: I think proving this would be a fantastic achievement. Compare it with the $x^2+y^4$ result of Friedlander-Iwaniec, and note that there are much more fourth powers than powers of two.

Comment: @GHfromMO ... hmmm yes, from that point of view, my hopes don't seem realistic ...